# Two-Box-Model of a nonlinear amplifier

Tags: autoregressive-model

A nonlinearity with memory can be modelled by a two-box-model, which consists of a filter and a memoryless nonlinearity. I am referring to chapter 5.3.2 of the book "Simulation of Communication Systems" by M.C.Jeruchim et. al. [here's a link to Google books](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=K1wKBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=simulation+of+communication+systems&ots=7mDBoZgf8R&sig=2MBW-b-8B6n9xfsYpEDjznft4mE#v=onepage&q=simulation%20of%20communication%20systems&f=false)

I am given the AM-AM- and the AM-PM-characteristic of an amplifier. I want to model the behavior of the amplifier to a two-tone input signal. To do so, I want to set up a two-box-model. The memoryless nonlinearity should be described by the given characteristics.

- But what does a filter before the memoryless nonlinearity do?
- What does an ARMA filter do?
- Can an ARMA filter be used to filter an analog signal (sine-waves) ?

Comment: Hi Luk, you brought up the term "two-box model", so I think it'd be only fair to us if you referred to the source where you've got that from. I'm not asking for this because I want to be nitpicky - it's just that I actually already answered a question you asked by pointing out a sentence in the paper you forgot to cite in the original version of your question, and had you specified your sources right from the start, you could have saved me a lot of work.

Comment: To my understanding, "two-box models" don't always consist of a filter and a nonlinearity, so your question **is** literature-specific, so you **must** at least specify which literature you're referring to.

Comment: you're right, I didn't think about it.

Comment: ARMA filters operate on discrete-time data. I've added some information to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is a linear time-invariant (LTI) system that adds memory to the model. Combined with a memoryless nonlinearity, the filter allows to model non-linear systems *with* memory, unlike a pure AM-AM and AM-PM model, which models a *memoryless* nonlinearity. An [ARMA-filter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Signal_Processing/Digital_Filters#ARMA_Filters) is the same as an [infinite-impulse response (IIR) filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response), which computes its output as a linear combination of weighted and delayed versions of the input and output signal. IIR filters need to be implemented by recursive structures.

An ARMA (or IIR) filter is a discrete-time (linear time-invariant) filter whose response $y[n]$ to an input sequence $x[n]$ is computed as follows:

$$y[n]=\sum_{m=0}^Mb_mx[n-m]+\sum_{l=1}^Na_ly[n-l]\tag{1}$$

where $b_m$ and $a_l$ are the filter coefficients, which are chosen such that a certain desired filter characteristic (e.g., low pass, high pass, etc.) is achieved.

Comment: thx, Matt! I am given a superposition of 2 sine-waves. I think this signal can be considered discrete as I am given the values of the signal at different time steps ( so I have a vector). I have a vector of the output signal as well. I think the main goal of a filter before my nonlinearity is to filter out the 3rd-degree intermodulation products of my output spectrum. At least it would be great, if this was possible! In equation (1), m and l are just the indices of the vector entries, right? And now my task is to determine $a_l$ and $b_m$ - is this where least squares is used?

Comment: @Luk: I'm not sure what your filter is supposed to do. Filtering out intermodulation products is something that *you* might want to do, but the actual task of the filter (together with the memoryless nonlinearity) is to model a given nonlinear system. So you have to choose the filter coefficients in such a way that your model matches your observation of the actual system.